# Switch to first tab in Notepad++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, tabs

Does anyone know if it is possible via shortcut to switch back to the very first tab in Notepad++? I know how to switch to next and previous tabs, but would like to switch back to the first tab.

Comment: Couldn't you record a macro of you clicking on the first tab?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to open the Window menu

Press `1` to open the first window, which is the same as the first tab.

Comment: To go to another specific window: `Alt+W, W`. This opens a window/tab list from which you can select whatever tab. You can also save or close a selection of tabs, or sort tabs.

Answer (score 4):

I found faster (than accepted answer) just pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>numpad number</kbd>

For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will send you to the very first tab, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to the second, and so on. Just in the same intuitive way it works for browsers.

Comment: Additionally if you want smarter navigation method, I suggest you install "navigateTo" plugin, it allows you to navigate by search and filtering. It is a quite nice feature.

Comment: this can be seen in menu Settings > Shortcut mapper and search for "tab"

Answer (score 2):

You could install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and use the following script - this is what I've done myself. It allows you to use ALT-1, ALT-2, ALT-3, etc. to choose those numbered tabs quickly, by automating what Wayne Johnston suggested.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad++
{
    !1::SendInput !w1
    !2::SendInput !w2
    !3::SendInput !w3
    !4::SendInput !w4
    !5::SendInput !w5
    !6::SendInput !w6
    !7::SendInput !w7
    !8::SendInput !w8
    !9::SendInput !w9
}
```

Believe me, once you start using AutoHotkey, a whole new world of automating and customising your apps' keyboard usage opens up. It's even kind of addictive once you get into it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it will show the list of tabs available, keep pressing tab without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to cycle between tabs list, else click on the tab name to switch to it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Is there anyway to set up a shortcut to go to the first tab though without having to cycle through?

Comment: `Use Ctrl+Tab it will show the list of tabs available` that's simply not true. It only displays the tab list when [MRU behavior](https://superuser.com/q/591785/241386) is enabled in preferences. And this doesn't answer the question in anyway, which is how to switch to the first tab with a shortcut. Of course everybody already knows Ctrl+Tab switches between tabs